# How would one make a unit converter in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering how, in objective c, one would go about making a unit converter, in particular one specific point: would you need a new block of code for each unit to be converted to every other unit. e.g.

meters - feet
meters - centimeters
meters - inches

etc then have a new code to convert feet to each of the units, then one for inches to each, another for centimetres to each unit etc, or is there some easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general all units conversions are of the same form:

```
valueInUnit1 = A * valueInUnit2 + B
```

`B` often even being zero (meters to feets, inches to meters, etc) -- and being non-zero only for a some cases (like converting temperature from Kelvins to Celcius)

What you only need is to keep a list of the values of A and B for each pair of units to convert one unit to another.

Note that you can even keep only main values (from metric system units to other units for example) and deduce the others, as from the formula above you can obviously conclude the reverse

```
valueInUnit2 = (valueInUnit1 - B) / A = (1/A) * valueInUnit1 + (-B/A)
```

So once you have the list of values A and B for every pair of units you want to convert from and to, you will only have one method to convert them all.

You can store the list of values A and B whereever you want, in a dedicated PLIST file, in a sqlite3 database, in CoreData, ... (for your case using a PLIST file will probably be much more easier. e.g. a NSDictionary whose keys are the name of the origin unit, and values are themselves NSDictionaries whose keys are destination units and values are the A and B pairs... -- that's just a suggestion, not the only solution)

Comment: so I would need to find the equation for each conversion (y=mx+b) and then when the code is called, sub in the string relating to that conversion then?

Comment: Exactly. Your app will probably propose to the use a list of acceptable units (in a UIImagePicker, a UITableView, or whatever) to choose the units to convert from and to, so it will be easy then to retrieve the values of the coefficients corresponding to the input and output units chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table with all the conversion factor and write a method which takes the conversion factor and the value which is meant to be converted. Therefore you need only one "block" of code.

Answer (score 0):

There's indeed an easier way, keep your units and conversion rules in a file or database. In most cases you need more or less simple arithmetic to convert the units. There is the program "units" in Unix or Linux, you could study the source and the unittab or units.tab.

Answer (score 0):

Do like United Nations or European Union do for translations: convert from any to reference then from reference to any other.

For physical units, a convenient reference is the [international system of units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units).